# How to publish documents (JS, CSOM)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

How to programmatically publish the main version of the document through Javascript?[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `SP.File.publish()` method present in `sp.js` to publish the major version of the document.

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246112.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Sample Code :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"
src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext',publishFile);
});
 var oFile;
 function publishFile() {
  //Get client context and web
 clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
 var oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
 //Get List and File object
 var oList = oWeb.get_lists().getByTitle('Demo Library');
 oFile=oWeb.getFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/Playground/Demo
 Library/Document.docx');
  //Publish the file and execute the batch
 oFile.publish();
 clientContext.load(oFile);
  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(QuerySuccess, QueryFailure);
 }
  function QuerySuccess() {
   //Get major version

    var majorVersion =oFile.get_majorVersion();
    console.log("Major Version - "+ majorVersion );
 }
  function QueryFailure(sender,args) {
      console.log('Request failed - '+args.get_message());
  }
</script>
```

Successful output of the published major version is shown below :
[image]

If you need more info you can download the JSOM book I have written from [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/ebooks/javascript-object-model-ecma-programming-in-sharepoint-2016-and-office_365)

How to publish the file is present in Page No : 58 .

Comment: Are you missing a `ctx.executeQueryAsync(...)`?

Comment: Only C#, JS no options...((

Comment: @MikhailZhuykov - Please see the updated answer with output

Comment: Awesome ! Great to know it worked !

Answer (score 3):

You can try below code to publish major version:

```
var library;
var clientContext;
var listItemCol;


function GetFileByFileName(itemName) {
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml(
'<View><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name=\'FileLeafRef\'/>' +
'<Value Type=\'Text\'>'+itemName+'</Value></Contains></Where></Query>' +
'<RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>'
);
listItemCol = library.getItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.load(listItemCol);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.updateItemProperties), Function.createDelegate(this, this.genericFail));=
}

function updateItemProperties(sender, args) {
var listItemEnumerator = listItemCol.getEnumerator();
var listItem;
while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
listItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
break;
}
// this is how we set properties on list item representing a file
listItem.set_item('Title', "some file title");
listItem.update();
var spfile = listItem.get_file();
spfile.publish("Published by app");
clientContext.load(listItem);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.genericSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.genericFail));
}

function genericSuccess(sender, args) {
alert('yay!');
}

function genericFail(sender, args) {
alert('oh no!');
}
```

Reference:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246112.aspx

Comment: Please check updated answer.

Comment: can you explain your usage of `Function.this` ?

Comment: This code isn't work, some errors.

Comment: Please check updated answer.